# Definition of connecting homomorphism for Mayer-Vietoris sequence

Tags: differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

Given a manifold $M$ and opens sets $U_1,U_2 \subseteq M$ such that $M=U_1 \cup U_2$, the Connecting Homomorphism for Mayer-Vietoris sequence is defined as $$\delta: H^p(U_1 \cap U_2) \rightarrow H^{p+1}(M) \\ [\omega] \mapsto \begin{cases} [-d(\rho_2 \omega)]  \quad\text{on}\ U_1 \\ [d(\rho_1 \omega)]  \quad \text{on} \ U_2  \end{cases}$$
where $\{\rho_j\}_{j=1,2}$ is a partition of unity subordinate to $\{U_j\}_{j=1,2}$.

So $d(\rho_j \omega)$ is an exact $(p+1)$-form for $j=1,2$. Why its cohomology class is not zero on $H^{p+1}(M)$?

Comment: Why *would* you expect $\delta([\omega])$ to be zero? The resulting differential form need not be exact.

Comment: @Kajelad A $(p+1)$-form $\eta $is exact if there exists a $p$-form $\gamma$ such that $\eta = d \gamma$, and in this case I have $d(\rho_j \omega)$ which is the differential of a $p$-form. Where am I wrong?

Comment: $\rho_1\omega$ is a smooth $p$-form on $U_2$, and $\rho_2\omega$ is a smooth $p$-form on $U_1$. It may not be the case that either extend to smooth $p$-forms on $M$.

Comment: What $p$-form do you think $\delta([\omega])$ is the differential of?

Comment: Try this explicitly for $H^1(S^1)$ to understand what you're doing wrong.